# Replicate all documents from all database buckets to a single database bucket in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

I have private database buckets for all users (using couch_peruser). A user can only access (read/write) his/her database bucket. I need to replicate all the documents residing in all the users's private Databases to a central Database for easy processing and analytics generation.

One way to do this is using the Futon and manually adding replicators for all DBs, since I have around 10K users (and their 10K DBs), that solution isn't easy.

Is there any way (any script or library) which accomplish this issue?

Comment: You could create daemon that listen to the _changes endpoint. Whenever a new user is created, you could add the replication rules into your _replicator database.